# Changing conditionally Record's values depending on one of the properties

Tags: typescript

So I want to make a sort of filtering system that has different kinds of filters.
Every filter has a `label` and `value` and some also have the `options` variable. I also added the `type` to distinguish between them.

So now I have an issue with this code:

```
export interface FilterValue {
    label: string;
    value: string | number;
}

export enum FilterTypes {
    TextInput,
    Picker,
    CheckboxGroup,
    Switch,
}

type SwitchFilter = {
    type: FilterTypes.Switch;
    value: boolean;
};

type TextFilter = {
    type: FilterTypes.TextInput;
    value: string;
};

type CheckboxFilter = {
    type: FilterTypes.CheckboxGroup;
    options: readonly FilterValue[];
    value: string[];
};
type PickerFilter = {
    type: FilterTypes.Picker;
    options: readonly FilterValue[];
    value: string;
};

export type Filters = Record<
    string,
    { label: string } & (
        | PickerFilter
        | CheckboxFilter
        | TextFilter
        | SwitchFilter
    )
>;

const filters = {
    chg: {
        label: "",
        type: FilterTypes.CheckboxGroup,
        value: [],
        options: [],
    },
    txi: {
        label: "",
        type: FilterTypes.TextInput,
        value: "",
    },
    pck: {
        label: "",
        type: FilterTypes.Picker,
        value: "",
        options: [],
    },
    swi: {
        label: "",
        type: FilterTypes.Switch,
        value: false,
    },
} satisfies Filters;
```

When I go to check what value does the `filters.swi.value` has it's always `false`. How should I make it so that it's `boolean` like in the `Filters` type?

Doing a `as Filters` removes the InteliSense from `filters` variable completely and smashes the property of `value` to a union type `boolean | string | string[]`

And doing a cast `as SwitchFilter` is not possible because it says `variable label is not on type SwitchFilter`

Is it even possible to do that without casting the variable itself to it's desired type or should I try something entirely new?

**EDIT**

To be exact, I have a class `Plugin` that has a `filter` object and `search` function. Each `Plugin` will have it's own `filters` and I'd like to be able to have InteliSense for each of them.

```
type ResultItem = string;

interface SearchOptions<Q extends Filters> {
    filters: Q;
}
export interface PluginBase {
    id: string;
    filters: Filters;
    version: string;
    search(
        options: SearchOptions<Filters>
    ): Promise<ResultItem[]>;
}
```

So when I create a new Plugin

```
class Plugin implements PluginBase {
    id = "";
    version = "";
    async search(options: SearchOptions<typeof this.filters>): Promise<ResultItem[]> {
        // I'd like here to have the intelisense depending on the filters from before, but this time with values properely set for each item.
        options.filters.chg.value // never[], but I want string[]
        options.filters.swi.value // false, but I want boolean

        return [];
    }
    filters = {
        chg: {
            label: "",
            type: FilterTypes.CheckboxGroup,
            value: [],
            options: [],
        },
        txi: {
            label: "",
            type: FilterTypes.TextInput,
            value: "",
        },
        pck: {
            label: "",
            type: FilterTypes.Picker,
            value: "",
            options: [],
        },
        swi: {
            label: "",
            type: FilterTypes.Switch,
            value: false,
        }
    } satisfies Filters;
}
```

And I would like to try something that'd change the static type of `filters` variable to version of it's type that has correct `value` types so that I won't have to write `as boolean` and `as string` and `as string[]` to every single `value` in filters

I tried with conditional logic like

```
type Filter2Values<
    Q extends Filters,
    Z extends keyof Filters
> = Q[Z]["type"] extends FilterTypes.Switch
    ? {
          value: string;
      }
    : Q[Z]["type"] extends FilterTypes.Picker
    ? { value: string }
/* and so on */
    : never;
```

and then only in search() doing `Filter2Values<typeof this.filters>`

But it didn't work...

[New link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Qsmj4VYjtemKIReilOBJNJBd8SS0jUpsqA+l4ApssuXKpMmaZZn0I8mCRGAqCgUCJRcPQlw7ekksyngGSaphWA4bg4DQw1hraSofl2f4+m9F5QUyKbhqlHh8TWprir5Lakp0bbGRABBBqSlxRrNCaUKO0MmTeBbeiDLwfH8c6LjGHhJoO26wHCM7puYS7xu+wHGVm0VHpdKBbpGS4vpu97IRSva8Vuw6koq06xOm4GEdhzYIYe1kIxKJHAs+6zKCndHWitXhMBhXh2wcUVeF0IA)

[Minimal rep. example](https://tsplay.dev/NBYEdw)

Comment: If you need more control over how a value is inferred than `satisfies` gives you, you could write a generic helper function... as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1QoOw).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: So it's not possible to do with types alone, without any additional functions? With just types? It does what I want, I just thought that maybe there could be a way to somehow change the `SearchOption` type or type of the parameter of `search` to achieve this. I like that the fitters are static at the start, now how to create a new type out of them with the same keys and with properly mapped type. (To `value` that's dependant on `type`)

Comment: Okay. I extrapolated your function based approach to use the generic type instead of using a function into: `export type FilterToValues<T extends Record<keyof T, { label: string; type: FilterType }>> = {[K in keyof T]: { type: T[K]["type"] } & Filters[string];};` and it did it. Thanks!

Comment: "Did it" how? Can you demonstrate with a full [mre]?  Should I write up my answer?  Or has the scope of the problem changed to involve "just types", in which case you might want to [edit] the question to clarify that (although it feels like moving goalposts from where I'm sitting).  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: Like I added in the comment, I wanted to change the filters types but not where the filters were defined, like in `search` function declaration or inside the `SearchOption` type. So that I have filters stay static and `never` etc. but the values of parameter `filters` in the `search` implementation would have correct typings (`string` and not `never`)

Comment: Sorry, I’m not following. Instead of just describing it, could you please show a [mre]?  Like, actual code? You could use tsplay.dev to present a short link to the TS playground, if that helps

Comment: I added minimal rep. example link. And here is the link to tsplay.dev with what I did in my code to solve it. https://tsplay.dev/mqq7qm

Answer (score 1):

If it's fixed like what you have, then `filters.swi.value` is `false`. It's actually a good thing then. Because it's not expected to change.

If you want the `false` to come as a boolean, you can literally write that: `false as boolean`. And don't worry, with your existing setup, it'll only work for `boolean`. It'll give you an error if you try to put a value with another type.

Comment: But what if I want it to change? Or to be exact I want to loop through every filter and pass them as they are to another function, just with the values changed (and only values) while still keeping the intelisense.

Comment: Sorry, I specified more what I meant.

Comment: Sorry I was in the middle of replying to this and then something happened. I think the best way for the dynamic scenario is the approach where you write `false as boolean` instead of `false` for example.